# How does the female body sense its own pregnancy?

Tags: human-biology, brain, reproduction, endocrinology, ovulation

I understand that after the fertilized ovum attached in the uterus the female body will not produce the required hormone surge for ovulation the next month. Therefore no new ovum will be sent down the fallopian tubes during pregnancy. My question is how does the body sense that there is a fertilized ovum in the uterus? Are there some kind of sensors for this? Is the ovum it self producing hormones which can be detected by the body? Does the brain combine a lot of "hints" to infer that there is pregnancy?

Originally the question came about in the context of chickens and how their body detects if new eggs should be produced based on if they are already sitting on an egg.

Comment: Just a nit-picky bit of info: it’s different in chickens. Chickens don’t go broody on one egg. They wait for a clutch of eggs. Women don’t wait for several zygotes to start gestation. Also, some research on your part must be attempted and shown in your post, otherwise it will probably be closed. Seems odd for a Q&A site, but it’s still the norm. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the pointer. The research about how this works in chickens turned out to be difficult as most of the internet is apparently just concerned with preventing chickens from going broody. I will try to add some more info about my research anyway. Thanks!